# Prove a base of $L(E,\mathbb{K})$ (Homework Assignement)

Tags: linear-algebra

First of all let me assess that this is about a graded homework I have to do. Please prioritize developing on how I should begin to answer the question rather than a quick answer. Yes it's graded but I'd much rather understand it than just copy paste an answer.

So this is the second part of the exercice. In the first part, we proved that :

> With $E=\mathbb{R}_3[X]$, $B = \{1+X,X+X^2,X^2+X^3,X^3\}$ is a base of E.

Now here is the question I'm having trouble with :

> Let $l_1(f) = f(0),l_2(f) = f'(0),l_3(f) = f"(0),l_4(f) = f^{(3)}(0), \forall f \in E$ be 4 linear forms on $E$.
>
> Show that $L=(l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4)$ is a base of $E^*$ the dual space of $E$.

I must confess I had some trouble 'visualizing' the concept of dual space but I think I got it down now. Still I'm not able to find how to prove $L$ is a base.

Thanks to everyone that might help, it's greatly apreciated :)

Comment: Can I just say that $dim E^* = dim E = 4$ and then given each $l_i$ are non colinears to each other then $L$ base of $E$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself the following questions.

1. What is a typical element of the dual space $E^{*}$? (ie is it number, matrix, set or what?)
2. Is there a link between the "size" of $E$ and the "size" of $E^{*}$?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I finally figured it out, thanks for your time, much apreciated =)

Answer (score 1):

$E^*$ has dimension $4$. We have four linear forms (i.e elements of $E^*$) so to prove they form a base it suffices to prove they are linearly independent. Assume we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^4\lambda_i\cdot l_i=0$$

This means the sum above applied to any vector (i.e any polynomial of degree not exceeding $3$) yields $0$. Let's apply it to the base we found in the first part. We get the following system of equations

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}\lambda_1=0\\2\lambda_2=0\\4\lambda_3=0\\6\lambda_4=0\end{array}\right.$$

This means the forms are independent and form a basis of $E^*$

Comment: This is exactly what I managed to find just after posting this question. I had trouble understanding the dual space so I wasn't thinking straight. Thanks for your time marwalix.

Comment: I accepted Kevin's answer to encourage him but your answer was good too, hope you don't mind =)